# Binding jqte (JQuery Text Editor) to a div from dart

Tags: jquery, dart, dart-js-interop, jqte

I need to translated the following JQuery code to Dart:

```
$("#writepad").jqte();
```

I 've tried the following but didn't succeed:

```
var jquery = new JsObject(context['window.jQuery("#writepad")']);
jquery.callMethod('jqte');
```

I'm trying this hoping that it may stop jqte from displaying dynamically generated buttons twice. Your help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With *dart:js* :

```dart
context.callMethod(r'$', ['#writepad']).callMethod('jqte');
```

`context` can be seen as an alias for js `window`.

Comment: Alexandre. Thank you for your response. DartEditor issues a warning about the dollar sign. It says: "Multiple markers at this line - Undefined name '' - Expected an identifier". I escaped $ and replaced $ with 'window.jQuery' but still it does not do what the JS equivalent does.

Comment: Ooops, I forgot to escape `$`. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you. Your code works. This answers my question. But I think I found a bug in dart where dart2js code interferes with dart code. Thank you again for your help.